# I can't click the links in Firefox and Chrome (they work in IE7)

Tags: language-agnostic

Its the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I can't click the last 3 links in the following code (when I use FF or Chrome):

HTML:

```
<div id="leftmanulist">
        <div class="abouttop">
        <ul class="aboutlist">
            <li class="index"><a>成立宗旨</a></li>
            <li><a href="instruments.html">樂器編制</a></li>
            <li><a href="performance.html">演奏曲目</a></li>
            <li><a href="clothes.html">服裝介紹</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutfalundafa.html">關於法輪大法</a></li>
            <li><a href="awards.html">各界褒獎</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="aboutbutton"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftmanulist{ background:url("images/abouttop.gif") no-repeat;
float: left;
margin: 2px 2px 5px 30px;
padding:39px 0 0 0;
width:237px;}
#leftmanulist ul li{line-height:35px;text-align:left; text-decoration:none;}
#leftmanulist ul li a{ text-decoration:none;}

#leftmanulist ul li:hover{ color:#0068FF;}
#leftmanulist ul li a:hover{ color:#0068FF;}

#leftmanulist ul li.index{ color:#0068FF;}
#leftmanulist ul li.index a{ color:#0068FF;}
.abouttop{background:url("images/leftmanulist_z.gif") repeat-y ;
padding:0 6px;  position:relative; z-index:0;
width:237px;}
.aboutlist{position:relative;left:28px;}
.aboutbutton{background:url("images/leftmanulist_b.gif") no-repeat;
width:237px; height:20px; position:relative; top:-17px; z-index:2;}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome when using only the code posted. Something else may be causing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, but then I might not have the complete HTML/CSS.

If I had to make a guess I'd say your aboutbutton element is probably overlapping the bottom links (as you're positioning it top: -17px; and it has a higher z-index than abouttop). Give abouttop a higher z-index and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Something is most likely overlapping those elements in Firefox/Chrome.  In Chrome, right click and **inspect element**.  This will take you to the element that's overlapping in the tools panel, then....can't help you any further without more information, but if you update the question with that info we can.

Hopefully just identifying the overlapping element is an "ahhhhh *that* damn thing" moment and problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I changed the z-index to 2 and worked.